# Requesting data from services behind gateway, which has authorized the access

Tags: architecture

I have created modular monolith which is agnostic of any authorization or authentication.
Authn/Authz happens in gateway/BFF.
This worked fine as long as user wanted to hit specific API resource, such as api/objects/1, as all authz had to do was to permit or deny the request.
For example:
[image: Specific resource]

But now that I had to develop an endpoint that would return list of objects which user has access to it created a problem.

If I hit API such as api/objects how would I list all the resources user has access to?

Would I need to ask Authz to retrieve list of IDs and then pass those in body of the request for backend to retrieve those from database?
For example:
[image: Collection of resources]

Of course, if no permissions exist I could short circuit the response and return empty array.

I already have looked into passing id as list in query such as resource?query=1,2,3,4,5.
But GET has limited characters in query. Also my IDs are long, as they're UUID. The internet doesn't say too much about approach like this.

Is this a valid approach?